# Can't extract description tag from yahoo weather api

Tags: php, xml, api

I have encountered a problem when trying to extract description with cdata from my yahoo weather api, i think the problem might be finding the exact path.

```html
<?php
 $url ="https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(55844479)%20where%20text%3D%22Riga%2C%20Lv%22)&format=xml&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";
 $error = "";
 $file = fopen($url, "r");
 
 if($file == false)
 {
  $error = "File open error";
 }
 else
 {
  $stringXML = "";
  while (feof($file)==false)
  {
   $stringXML.= fread($file, 8192);
  }
  $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($stringXML);
  fclose($file);

  $description = $xml->results->link->description;

 }
?>


<html>
 <head>
  <title>Yahoo weather API</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 
  <h1>Yahoo weather api</h1>
<?php

 if($error == "")
 {
  echo "<h3>Description:".$description."</h3>";
 }
 else
 {
 echo "<p>".$error."</p>";
 }

?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Anyone mind helping me out? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description is not in the link. Use:

```
$description = $xml->results->channel->description;
```

To get the description with the CDATA inside the item tag, use:

```
$description = $xml->results->channel->item->description;
```

Comment: Thank you! However i need the second description tag, the one which contains cdata :)

Comment: It's inside the *item* so it would be $description = $xml->results->channel->item->description; See the edit @RalfsR

Comment: Thank you very much, working good now!